# Proving Two Sets are Equal - Infinite Sets - Example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let

$$A = \{x | x = 2n+1, n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ and

$$B = \{x | x = 2m-21, m\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ 
I am trying to prove $A =B.$ I understand that I need to prove  $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$; But my difficulty is how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $m \in \mathbb Z$ in the definition of $B$?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes - Changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me solve one of the directions. I would like to prove that $A\subseteq B$. How do I do it? I take some arbitrary element of $A$ and show that it must also be an element of $B$.

So take some $x\in A$. By definition of $A$, I can write $x=2n+1$ for some integer $n$. If I can somehow also write $x$ as $x=2m-21$ for an integer $m$, then I know that $x\in B$ by definition of $B$.

To do this, I rewrite $x=2n+1$ as follows, where I underway use the trick of adding $0$ (which does nothing), but I disguise $0$ as $21-21$:

$$x=2n+1=2n+1+(21-21)=2n+(1+21)-21=2n+22-21=2(n+11)-21.$$

But $m=n+11$ is an integer! So if I plug $m=n+11$ into this expression, I get

$$x=2m-21,$$

which exactly means that $x$ is an element of $B$.

Comment: Would I have to follow the exact same procedure to show that B⊆A

Comment: Yeah, the other direction will in essence be exactly the same. @RandomMath

Answer (score 0):

$2n+1=2n+1+(21-21)=2n+22-21=2(...)-21$ so $A\subset B$. Other side is similar.

Comment: How did u get 21-21? - it doesnt really make sense to me in how you jumped to that - and what about for B Subset A

Comment: I only add 21 and (-21) to 2n+1

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in A$, $x=2n+1=2(n+11)-21\in B$ $\Rightarrow \forall x\in A, x\in B \Rightarrow A\subseteq B$.

If $x\in B$, $x=2m-21=2(m-11)+1\in A$ $\Rightarrow \forall x\in B, x\in A \Rightarrow B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Would you be able to write in steps what you did? I understand the definition of Set Equality but it confuses me when actually applying

Answer (score 0):

Do you know any number theory?

You can prove the sets are equal if you can prove that $x = 2n + 1$ and $x = 2m - 21$ have the same solutions.

Consider the diophantine equation:

$$x - 2n = 1$$

By Bezout's lemma, this has a solution as long as $\operatorname{gcd}(x,-2) | 1$. In other words, as long as $x$ is odd.

Etc.