# Prove a set is a subset of another.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove $A⊆B$ where A and B are defined as:
${A =\{x | x = 2n + 1}\}$
${B =\{x | x = 2m - 21}\}$
where $n,m∈\mathbb{Z}$

I know that I need take an arbitrary element from A and show that it works in B, but I'm stuck on how to do it in this example.

Comment: This question has already been asked and already has several answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252640/proving-two-sets-are-equal-infinite-sets-example/1252651#1252651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in A$, $x=2n+1$. Take $m=n+11$ so $2m-21=2n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$2n+1 = 2n +22-21 = 2(n + 11) -21 $$ and $n+11 \in \Bbb Z $.